# Does $u$ solve $(-\Delta)^s u =0$ in $(-r, r)$ and $u=g$ in $\mathbb R\setminus (-r, r)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, fractional-calculus

Let $g\in C(\mathbb R, \mathbb R)$ and let $r>0$. Consider the function
$$u(x)=\begin{cases}
0 &\mbox{ in } (-r, r)\\
g &\mbox{ in } \mathbb R\setminus (-r, r)
\end{cases}$$

Let $s\in (0, 1)$ and let $(-\Delta)^s u$ denotes the fractional laplacian of $u$ (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Laplacian).

I am trying to understand if the function $u$ solves the problem
$$\begin{cases}
(-\Delta)^s u =0 &\mbox{ in } (-r, r)\\
u=g &\mbox{ in } \mathbb R\setminus (-r, r)
\end{cases}.$$

I would say that $u$ does solve it, but when I wrote that during the last week assignment, it was marked as an error and the lecturer said that I have to justify my writing and prove that it holds (or not).

My argument is that since $u=0$ in $(-r, r)$ hence its fractional laplacian is null and $u=g$ in $\mathbb R\setminus (-r, r)$ by definition. Maybe it is not enough.

Anyone could please help me to prove (or disprove) that?

Comment: The fractional laplacian is a non-local operator so that your attempt to show that $(-\Delta)^s u = 0$ on $(-r,r)$ is not correct.

Comment: You should accept one of the other answers. I made a mistake, because I did no think about the fractional Laplacian at all. As it is, it's clearly wrong, which I'm sorry for. Unfortunately, I cannot delete it while it is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have accepted an answer that says that your $u$ does solve the desired equation, let me explicitly provide a choice of $g$ for which $(-\Delta)^s u(x) \ne 0$ for $x \in (-r, r)$ to make clear that your solution is incorrect.

I will use the definition of the fractional laplacian given by
\begin{align*}
(-\Delta)^s u(x) = c_{d,s} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{u(x) - u(y)}{|x-y|^{d + 2s}} dy
\end{align*}
for a suitable strictly positive constant $c_{d,s}$ which is given explicitly at the wikipedia page you linked.

With your choice of $u$, for $x \in (-r,r)$ we then have
\begin{align*}
(-\Delta)^s u(x) = c_{d,s} \int_{-\infty}^{-r} \frac{- g(y) }{|x-y|^{d + 2s}} dy + c_{d,s} \int_r^\infty \frac{- g(y) }{|x-y|^{d + 2s}} 
\end{align*}
It's then easy to see that if $g$ is a strictly negative function then for your $u$, $(-\Delta)^s u(x) > 0$ and if $g$ is strictly positive then $(-\Delta)^su(x) < 0$. As an example, consider $g$ given by $g(y) = -1$ for all $y$.

Then
\begin{align*}
(-\Delta)^s u(x) = c_{d,s} \int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus(-r,r)} {|x-y|^{-d - 2s}} dy > 0.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Based on the definition of $(-\Delta)^{s}$ via the Fourier transform, it is not at all obvious to me if/why $u = 0$ on $(-r, r)$ implies that $(-\Delta)^{s}u = 0$ on $(-r, r)$ in the sense of distributions. Specifically, it doesn't seem like $\phi \in C_c^{\infty}(-r, r) \implies (-\Delta)^s \phi = 0$ on $(-r, r)$. In other words, it isn't clear to me that the operator $(-\Delta)^s$ acts locally.